# python cyrillic decode

Tags: python, decode

I'm trying to print cyrillic chars selected from mysql. Here is my code:
content id DB is cp1251

```
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="XXX", passwd="XXXX" )
>>> cursor = db.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("""select id,title,cat,text,tags,date from db1.table1;""")
>>> test=cursor.fetchone()
>>> somevar=test[1]
>>> somevar=somevar.decode('utf8')
>>> print somevar
Result: ?????? ?? ????????
```

Please guide me how to print this correctly. Thx.

Comment: What does your original string look like?

Comment: As @summea points out, adding an example of with a current output (before you try to decode it) would avoid us just guessing what the problem is - and improves your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me (got it from [here](http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2007/12/17/python-mysqldb-and-utf-8)):

```py
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", config.db_user, config.db_pwd, config.db_name)

# here's the magic
db.set_character_set("utf8")
dbc = db.cursor()
dbc.execute("SET NAMES utf8;")
dbc.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;")
dbc.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8;")

# and here goes your SELECT for cyrillic fields
dbc.execute("SELECT id, title, cat, text, tags, date FROM db1.table1;")

# and then you just get the results
test = dbc.fetchone()
somevar = test[1]
print somevar
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
somevar = somevar.decode('cp1251')
```

If that does not help, try to add charset='cp1251' parameter in MySQLdb.connect and there is use_unicode parameter, maybe you should use it to...

---

all connect parameter you can find here https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/connections.py

```
use_unicode
```

If True, text-like columns are returned as unicode objects
using the connection's character set. Otherwise, text-like
columns are returned as strings. columns are returned as
normal strings. Unicode objects will always be encoded to
the connection's character set regardless of this setting.

```
charset
```

If supplied, the connection character set will be changed
to this character set (MySQL-4.1 and newer). This implies
use_unicode=True.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, I tried decode('cp1251'), decode('utf8'), decode('utf-8'), encode('cp1251'), encode('utf8'), encode('utf-8') but without success :( any other ideas ?

Comment: database charset is utf, but table charset is cp1251