# How to read non-english characters from database in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I am trying to read entries from mysql db in python using pymysql. Entries in database are in regional languages.
e.g. 74 погода is one such entry
I have written code like this:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(ip, user, pass, db, charset="utf8")
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute("select val from my_table")
r = cur.fetchone()

>>> r
('74 ??????',)
>>> r[0].encode("utf-8").strip()
'74 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0'
```

Here I am not getting the data as it that is present in the database.

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907509/python-cyrillic-decode

Comment: Please let us know as @AnatoliiChmykhalo is also a pythonic guru from your neck of the woods

Comment: This is easy way to print it:
`a = '74 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0'
>>> print a.decode("utf-8")
74 погода`

Comment: PLEASE specify which version of Python you are using.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem consistent for Python 2 (where pymysql would indeed have returned a byte string, but there is no byte string that renders `??????` that can be implicitly-decoded-then-encoded to recover anything but question marks), or Python 3 (where pymysql would have returned a unicode string, which could conceivably render as question marks if your terminal was badly broken; but then would show the encoded byte string with a `b''` prefix). Your UTF-8 encoded output at the end looks fine.

Comment: @AnatoliiChmykhalo It worked. Thanks.

Comment: [_various python notes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python) .

Answer (score 1):

This is because MySQLdb normally tries to encode everythin to latin-1. This can be fixed by executing the following commands right after you've etablished the connection:

```
db.set_character_set('utf8')
dbc.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
dbc.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
dbc.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

db is the result of MySQLdb.connect(), and dbc is the result of `db.cursor()*.

Comment: OP already set the connection encoding to UTF-8 in the `connect()` call. pymysql does not have a `set_character_set` method. You should never try to set connection encoding by executing queries—that only changes the encoding the server side will use, and doesn't let the client side know what encoding is in use, which can make its escaping fail (security hole for East Asian encodings). Throwing all those `SET` queries at it is pure superstition.